# How can I ignore obsolete type errors when running Live Unit Testing in VS 2022 enterprise?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2022, live-unit-tests

I have a solution with about 58 projects, including 10 test projects. There's only one I'm interested in running, that relates to my team's work.

I can run the test project manually from the Test Explorer, and it builds with all tests passing fine.

However, when I set up Live Unit Testing, the build fails due to obsolete types being used in some another projects. I don't want to replace all the type references since that code is managed by other teams.

Here are my [VS2022 LUT settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8UBm.png).

I have only added the test project I'm interested in to the LUT playlist. I also tried replacing some of the obsolete types (I only had 3 errors initially) but the compiler then found dozens more...

I increased the logging level on LUT to verbose, but that didn't give anything useful. There aren't any other settings I can see for LUT to ignore certain projects or errors.

I have looked up the MS documentation on the [obsolete] attribute, but I'm not sure why I get the error on LUT and not on regular test or debug builds.

The .csproj of a project that fails has this line: `<TreatWarningsAsErrors>True</TreatWarningsAsErrors>` and setting it to `False` allows LUT to build it. But I don't want to have to change dozens of .csprojs just for running some tests.

Is there any other way to mark errors as warnings for live unit testing?

Comment: In your question, TreatWarningsAsErrors is indeed a nice solution. You can also check out some related [documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting `<TreatWarningsAsErrors>false</TreatWarningsAsErrors>` you can add `<NoWarn>CS0618</NoWarn>` to the project files. That's probably going to help everybody, because others will have the same problem as well.

You can also add a section such as the following to your `Directory.Build.props` file (should be in the root of your project structure):

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(MSBuildProjectName.EndsWith('UnitTest')) AND '$(MSBuildProjectExtension)' == '.csproj'">
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);CS0618</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

This will disable the warning for all projects whose name ends with "UnitTest".

Comment: Thanks! When I use the props file I get the following error instead: "StreamJsonRpc.ConnectionLostException: The JSON-RPC connection with the remote party was lost before the request could complete." Any ideas what that could indicate?

Comment: I've searched for other threads and it seems like this was a common error with VS 2019, but I can't find anything specific to live unit testing and VS 2022

Comment: I've never seen this error, and I have no clue how this could be related. Honestly, I rarely use life unit testing and run the tests only on demand. But then the above tricks work just fine with the latest version as well.

Comment: I was able to use the Directory.Build.props approach, once I wrapped the example text in a `<Project>...PropertyGroup stuff here...</Project>` attribute. Without that it threw the JSON-RPC error above 

I ran into other build issues (missing Microsoft.WebApplication.targets file on the specified path) but that's out of the scope of this question so I'll mark this complete for now :)